# why we need tf.arg_max(Y,1) with softmax in tensorflow?

Tags: label, softmax, hypothesis-test, argmax

when I write the tensorflow demo, I find this **`arg_max()`** function in the definition of **`correct_predition`**

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
            logits=hypothesis,labels=Y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.arg_max(hypothesis,1),tf.arg_max(Y,1))
```

**Returns the index with the largest value across axes of a tensor.**(this is from the API from TF)

for we use '**`softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`**',

the prediction (**`hypothesis`**) are presented as the probability

we will get the index of largest probability of prediction by the **`arg_max()`** function for **`hypothesis`**

but `Y` is labels, **it is not the probability why we need use `tf.arg_max(Y,1)`**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arg_max(hypothesis) is returning an INDEX. 
Y is a length 10 one-hot vector.
tf.equal() can't do anything sensible here because the two things are not compatible.

So, arg_max(Y) returns an INDEX.
Now tf.equal() can do a sensible thing: 1 if the prediction matches the target, 0 otherwise.

Note the arg_max() is not a function about probabilities: it's just a function to return the index of the biggest element.

Comment: thanks a lot. ***Y is a length 10 one-hot vector.*** is important to this question.